# Midpoint displacement algorithm in c++(make hight map for tank like scorched earth)

Tags: c++, windows, algorithm, sdl-2, 2d-games

**Midpoint displacement algorithm in c++(make height map for tank-like scorched earth)**

Now, the problem is that I can't get it to work properly. What can I do?

Here is what I get when it is executed.

Result:

[image: Result]

Expected:

[image: Expected]

**Note that the screen y-axis is in SDL2 from up to down 0 is up 1000 +- is down**

Before the function I have the initializing variables:

```
std::vector<int> points(g_SCREEN_WIDTH);
    // Gives us a power of 2 based on our width

double Displacement = 100;       //diplacment 1 to 1000
double roughness = 2500;   //between 1 to 500000 more smoother
double itrations = g_SCREEN_WIDTH;
float range = 2;
bool parlien = 0, onlyOne =0;


srand(time(NULL));

int choose;

choose = rand() % 3 + 1;
switch (choose) {
case 1: {Displacement = rand() % g_SCREEN_HEIGHT; break; }
case 2: {Displacement = g_SCREEN_HEIGHT; break; }
case 3: {Displacement = rand(); break; }
}


choose = rand() % 5 + 1;

switch (choose) {
case 1: {roughness = rand() % 250 + 50; break; }
case 2: {roughness = rand() % 500 + 250; break; }
case 3: {roughness = rand() % 2500 + 500; break; }
case 4: {roughness = rand() % 5000 + 2500; break; }
case 5: {roughness = rand() % 50000 + 5000; break; }
        break;
}


choose = rand() % 4 + 1;
switch (choose) {
case 1: {itrations = rand() % 64 + 1; break; }
case 2: {itrations = rand() % 150 + 64; break; }
case 3: {itrations = rand() % 265 + 150; break; }
case 4: {itrations = rand() % 1024 + 265; break; }
        break;
}



//itrations = 12;
int mountents;
mountents = rand() % 3;
//itrations = 16;

// mountents = 1;

// first initializing for the points
{
    int y = rand() %(int)Displacement;
    points.at(0) = y;
    y = rand() %(int)Displacement;
    points.at(g_SCREEN_WIDTH - 1) = y;
}


//parlien = 0;

Displacement = (g_SCREEN_HEIGHT/8);  //more its little it  smother
roughness = 0.5;        //more its little it going up
itrations = 256;

std::cout << "Displacement:" << Displacement << "\n";
std::cout << "roughness:" << roughness << "\n";
std::cout << "itrations:" << itrations << "\n";
std::cout << " g_SCREEN_WIDTH:" << g_SCREEN_WIDTH << "\n";
```

here is the function

```
int func(double left, double right,std::vector<int> *points, double roughness, double segmnets, double Displacement, double itrations,int mountents,float range)
{
    double mid=(left+right)/2;  //it gets the midpoint of the segment we get here
    if (Displacement <= 1) Displacement = 1;
    //std::cout << "Displacement:" << Displacement << "\n";
    
    int y;
    

    if (range < 1) range = 1;
    if (mid <= 1) return 1;
    if (segmnets > itrations - 1) return 1;
    if (segmnets >= g_SCREEN_WIDTH) return 1;

    int Choose;
    
    
    
    y = -1;
    int cnt = 0;
    while (y<25 || y>g_SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    {
        y = ((points->at(left) + points->at(right)) / 2);
        float r = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        y = y + Displacement * r;
        y = abs(y);
            y= ::g_SCREEN_HEIGHT - y;  
            cnt++;
            if (cnt > 2) { std::cout << "cnt++:" << "\n"; y = rand() % (int)Displacement; break; }
    }

    

    if (y < 25) y = 25;
    if (y > g_SCREEN_HEIGHT) y = g_SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1;
    


    left= mid / 2;
    right = mid + (mid / 2);
    

    if (mid > 0 && mid < g_SCREEN_WIDTH)  
    {
        points->at(mid) = y;

    }

        
    Displacement /= 2;

        func(0,mid, points, roughness, segmnets * 2, Displacement, itrations, mountents,range);


        
        //for the rigths
        func(mid, g_SCREEN_WIDTH-1, points, roughness, segmnets * 2, Displacement, itrations, mountents,range);
        
}
```

Comment: Probably getting the parameters right takes some tweaking. Have you tried looking at some [source code?](http://www.scorch2000.com/downloads.html)?

Comment: Thx didn't found in the past but thx for the idea it will help a lot and the link.

Comment: What I mean is, if you zoom in on your result, I think it looks more like Scorched Earth? I think the original is probably using a similar algorithm.

Comment: Wow i thought about it, but i didn't continue with this  idea ,I will try it thx.

Comment: This part seems obviously wrong.  What's it for? `y = abs(y); y= ::g_SCREEN_HEIGHT - y`

Comment: @mattTimmermans this code is y = abs(y); y= ::g_SCREEN_HEIGHT - y   adding more higher  movements in y to create Mountains ,  before that i think I need to start arranging my code and try to understand more in depth what each code does to understand how it works thx for all helping :-).